# Right way of finding memory leaks in game written in Go

Tags: go, memory, memory-leaks

I am writing a game in Go. I was told my code was leaking memory. What would be the right approach to pinpoint the cause of the leaks?

I know **pprof** exists but as far as I know it can be used when your app uses the http package and my app is a simple game and it does not make use of any netowrk connectivity.

Comment: There is no such limit in pprof, you can use it whether you have network connections or not. See https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/

Comment: It may be useful if you mention some details about the game, especially its gui part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly create profiles without an http server using the [runtime/pprof package](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/). There's also [github.com/pkg/profile](https://godoc.org/github.com/pkg/profile) by Dave Cheney, a wrapper for runtime/pprof with a simpler API. You can use signal handlers to enable and disable profiling, for instance.

That being said, nothing stops you from starting an HTTP server, just for pprof. I find that much more convenient because then you can easily create any profile on demand.

```
// +build debug

package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    _ "net/http/pprof/"
)

func init() {
    log.Println("Launching pprof server")
    go func() { log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3030", nil)) }()
}
```

This uses a build tag so you can enable the server in development but exclude it from production builds. Compile with `-tags debug` to enable the server. See [Build Constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/pprof/ package to write memory profiles on disk (you can do it let's say once in a minute). After that just run `go tool pprof` (inuse_space mode) on few of them and look if there are some parts where inuse_space is growing

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the pprof discussed before, it might also be useful to check **heap** **allocation** by doing an escape analysis of your code (e.g. if file is main.go) by:

`go build -gcflags=-m main.go`

This immediately gives you an idea of things like if you are passing **pointers** around **unnecessarily** which can be avoided.

[Here is a short article](https://tennexas.com/how-to-check-improve-performance-in-go/) which goes through various ways you can make your program more efficient.